# How to remove containing div and add a class to ul using wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I want to generate this markup:

```
    <ul class="nav barbar-nav">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
```

From reading the [wordpress function reference for the wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function i think i should be calling this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav barbar-nav' ) );
```

But when i run that, i get the following:

```
<div class="nav barbar-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want to use this because of a special CSS formatting you're trying to use?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to use a bootstrap theme so i need to format the markup how the theme expects it.

Comment: can you post relevant lines from your functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $args = array(
                'menu'            => 'main-menu', 
                'container'       => '', 
                'container_class' => 'false', 
                'container_id'    => '',
                'menu_class'      => 'nav barbar-nav', 
                'echo'            => true,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
      ); ?>
      <?php wp_nav_menu( $args); ?>
```

Try setting all the arguments for the wp_nav_menu function below Don't erase the paraments, just leave them blank.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite confusing, but that's how the `fallback_cb` is formatted (see [`wp_page_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu)). Once you assign an actual nav menu to the theme location, the markup will be as expected. You can write your own callback to obtain similar markup when a fallback menu is displayed.